# Animating layer in OpenLayers4

Tags: javascript, openlayers, animation

Is there a way to include animate properties of a vector layer (GeoJSON)?

```
var highlightStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: '#fff',
      width: 1
    }),
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.1)'
    })
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as a basic example something like this would change the stroke width and fill opacity on a 10 second cycle

```
var timer = 0;

var style = function(feature) {
  return new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: '#fff',
      width: (timer%10)+1
    }),
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'rgba(255,0,0,' + (((timer%10)+1)/10) + ')'
    })
  });
}

var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: source,
  style: style
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [raster, vector],
  target: 'map',
  view: view
});

setInterval( function(){
  timer++;
  vector.setStyle(style);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Is it possible to include the setInterval() function in the style variable itself? I have some 'if' conditions to check before applying the style to the 'vector' layer. Currently, it animates the entire vector layer and not based off those set conditions. Something similar to [this](https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/vector-layer.html?q=vector+group) but with an if clause as the value of property 'style'. Thank you!

Comment: It would be easier to put the if clauses in the style function, you can test properties and types of features, the view resolution and any of your own variables which are in scope (similar to timer `above`).  Style functions such can very complex e.g. https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/resources/mapbox-streets-v6-style.js used in https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/mapbox-vector-tiles.html